# dropdown list show two dropdown list when using selectpicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, double, bootstrap-select

i am using selectpicker the dropdown shows twice like in the image

[image: (click this link for image)]

when i  remove selectpicker class it show nomal dropdown list

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card-box">
            <h4 class="m-t-0 header-title"><b>Select app</b></h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="p-20">
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-white">
                            <option>abc</option>
                            <option>xyz</option>
                            <option>123</option>
                        </select> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    $(":file").filestyle({input: false});
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure "bootstrap-select.css" is loaded correctly.

It has .bootstrap-select > select style that is applied to style element which will hide the normal dropdown list.

Inspect the select and take a look above style is applied there? I have used above code and it is working fine when "bootstrap-select.css" is loaded.

Comment: it is loaded in my xyz.html.erb page using the ink <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" /> it is also available in the same path

Comment: .bootstrap-select > select {
   22    position: absolute !important;
   23    bottom: 0;
   ..
   30    border: none;
   31  }

Comment: Please provide code of complete page, including references to js and css. So that I can use exactly same references to js and css in my code. As with the code you provided it is working for me.

Comment: I added bootstrap-select.css stylesheet but it does not work for me

Comment: Do you see "bootstrap-select > select" style being applied to your select element?

Comment: @khalidh can you please upload full code here. I'm facing same probem.

Comment: @AkashSethi In my case i have added 2 bootstrap.min.css files, so the issue happens, removed the one file then its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was mistakenly loading CSS file under a condition, just moved CSS file out of condition and made it global.

So, yes please check if `bootstrap-select` CSS is loading or not.